# Getting an error : The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#

I wanna insert one dataset col value into another datset value one by one but there were getting an error : The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(dsArea.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
{
  if (dsArea.Tables[0].Columns["AreaName"].ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Columns["AreaName"].ToString())
  {
     dsCustReg.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AreaName"].ToString() = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AreaName"].ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot assign into a method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.ToString()`

```
dsCustReg.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AreaName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AreaName"].ToString();
```

Comment: you have not removed ``ToString()`` in your answer

Comment: can u please tell how to get that above matched dataset value?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `ToString()` while assinging it to a variable try

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(dsArea.Tables[0].Rows.Count);

for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
{
    if (dsArea.Tables[0].Columns["AreaName"].ToString() == ds.Tables[0].Columns["AreaName"].ToString())
    {
        dsCustReg.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AreaName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["AreaName"].ToString();
    }
}
```